# getting a specific word using .match and regular expression not working

Tags: jquery

I am having a little trouble with regular expression.

I want to match a regular expression in  a sentence.

Example :

```
John has two candy ::123::
```

and i am using this code to look for it:

```
var getid = x$('div').html().match(/::([^:]+)::/g);
```

To get the 123 our of the sentence.

So what's my problem here?
I kept on getting an undefined value for getid var.

Comment: yeah x$ is the alias. but it's getting an undefined value.

Comment: Do you have only div in the page? It might be a good idea to access the element by id.

Comment: i am using (this).html(); because above it its the div ID. on click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `g` flag. You don't use it with `String#match`. Remove it and it works fine ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/onosuq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/edit)):

```
var getid = x$('div').html().match(/::([^:]+)::/);
if (getid) {
    display("Found: " + getid[1]);
}
else {
    display("Not found");
}
```

If you want to find all of the matches in the text, use `RegExp#exec` and a loop (and the `g` flag) ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/2/edit)):

```
var rex = /::([^:]+)::/g;
var str = x$('div').html();
var getid;
while (getid = rex.exec(str)) {
    display("Found: " + getid[1]);
}
```

(For greater clarity, you might use

```
while ((getid = rex.exec(str)) != null) {
```

...since having an assignment in a test looks like a `=` instead of `==` typo; but it comes to the same thing other than readability.)

---

Re your comment below asking about `x$(this)`, it should make any difference. Here are the above examples reworked to use `x$(this)`:

- One match: [Example](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/4) | [source](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/4/edit)
- Loop: [Example](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/5) | [source](http://jsbin.com/onosuq/5/edit)

Comment: Hi i removed the g flag its still getting an undefined value. i am using $(this) , is it okay or will it affect the .match?

Comment: @sm21guy: `x$(this)` to get the element won't make any difference (provided the `this` in question is an element with the text), there must be some other issue with the code. Cmpare it with the working examples above and you should be able to find it. I've added examples using `x$(this)`.